# Prove that function $f(p)=(ap+b)mod\;m$ is bijective if and only if $gcd(a,m)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$a,b,m,p$ are integers and $m\geq 2$

$f(p)=(ap+b)mod\;m$ is a function from set $A$ to set $B$.

That is, $p\in A$ and $f(p)\in B$,

Prove that

i) If function $f$ is one-to-one and onto (bijective), then $gcd(a,m)=1$.

ii) If $gcd(a,m)=1$, then function $f$ is bijective.

Also, set $A=$ set $B=$ set $Z_m$. Therefore NO TWO different elements in $A$ (or $B$) are congruent modulo $m$

Comment: i)Suppose $gcd(a,m)\neq 1$
ii)Suppose f isn't bijective, pick gcd(a,m)=1
Both will contradict.

Comment: How to derive a contradiction for i) with $gcd(a,m)>1$ and $f$ bijective ? If $gcd(a,m)>1$,does any multiple of $a$ exist which is NOT congruent to any value in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,m-2,m-1\}\;mod\;m$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If $f(p)=ap+b(mod\;m)$ is a bijection, then $gcd(a,m)=1$"
is equivalent to its contrapositive 
"If $gcd(a,m)\neq 1$, then $f(p)$ is NOT a bijection"

And

"If $gcd(a,m)=1$, then $f(p)$ is a bijection"
is equivalent to its contrapositive 
"If $f(p)$ is NOT a bijection, then $gcd(a,m)\neq 1$"

Hence proving "$f(p)$ is a bijection if and only if $gcd(a,m)=1$"
is equivalent to
proving "$f(p)$ is NOT a bijection if and only if $gcd(a,m)\neq 1$".

Proof:

Suppose $f(p)$ is NOT a bijection. That is, assume $f(p)$ is many to one or NOT onto.

Then there $\exists p,p'\in A$ such that $f(p)=f(p')$ where $p\neq p'$. 
That is, $(ap+b)mod\;m=(ap'+b)mod\;m$ where $p\neq p'$.

This means
$m|ap+b-(ap'+b)\Rightarrow m|a(p-p')$

If $m\not|a$, then $m|(p-p')$.
Therefore, $p\equiv p'(mod\;m)$ which is a contradiction because NO TWO different values in $A=Z_m$ are congruent modulo $m$.

Thus, $m|a$ which implies $gcd(a,m)=m\neq1$. Hence, if $f(p)$ is NOT bijective, then $gcd(a,m)\neq 1$.

Proof of the converse:

We are given $gcd(a,m)\neq 1$.
Is it possible to have $f(p)=f(p')$ if $p\neq p'$ ?. 
That is, do $p\neq p'$ exist in $A=Z_m$ such that $ap+b\equiv ap'+b(mod\;m)$ ?

$gcd(a,m)>1\Rightarrow 1<lcm(a,m)<am$. **We can derive this result by factoring the $gcd(a,m)$ out of $am$.**

Because, $p,p'\in A=Z_m$, choose $p=0$ and $p'=\frac{lcm(a,m)}{a}<\frac{am}{a}=m$ and $p'>0$

These values for $p$ and $p'$ satisfies the congruence and makes $f$ NOT bijective.

Thus, if $gcd(a,m)>1$, then $f(p)$ is NOT bijective.

Thus it is proved that $f(p)$ is NOT bijective if and only if $gcd(a,m)>1$ which is equivalent to saying "$f(p)$ is bijective if and only if $gcd(a,m)=1$".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ Since $\,x\mapsto x+b\,$ is bijective it suffices to show $\,h(x) = ax\,$ is bijective.  But

$$\begin{align} h\rm\ is\ bijective &\iff \ker h \equiv  0\\
& \iff  ax\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, x\equiv 0\\
& \iff m\mid ax\,\Rightarrow\ m\mid x \\
& \iff \gcd(m,a) = 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $ker h$ ?

Comment: It's linear algebra language for the roots of the linear map $\,h.\ $ But you can safely omit that if you don't know linear algebra.

Comment: Because $h$ is bijective, multiples of $a$ are congruent $mod\;m$ to every value in $Z_m$. I mean that there is NO value in $Z_m$ which is NOT congruent $mod\;m$ to any multiple of $a$. But how does this lead to saying that $a$ and $m$ are relatively prime ?

Comment: Which step in the proof is not clear?

Comment: Sorry, i do NOT know linear algebra. So i could NOT go past the 1st step. I just want to know that if $ax_0\equiv 0,\;ax_1\equiv 1,\;ax_2\equiv 2,\;\ldots,ax_{m-2}\equiv m-2,\;ax_{m-1}\equiv m-1$ modulo $m$, then how to show that $gcd(a,m)=1$ ?

Comment: As I said, just omit that part. Then where are you stuck?

Comment: Ok. But i also can't understand step 2. How $h$ being bijective imply ONLY $ax\equiv 0(mod\;m)$ ? Isn't it true that for some other values of $x$, $ax\equiv 1,2,\ldots, m-1\;(mod\;m)$ ?

Comment: I just want to know if $\not\exists k\in Z_m$ for which $k\not\equiv ax\;mod\;m$ for some integer $x$, then how to derive $gcd(a,m)=1$ ?

Comment: @Sak If $\,h$ isn't $1\!-\!1$ then $\,ab\equiv ac\,$ for $\,b\not\equiv c\,$ so $\,a(b\!-\!c)\equiv 0\,$ so $\,ax\equiv 0\,$ has solution $\,x = b\!-\!c\not\equiv 0.\,$ Conversely if $\,ad\equiv 0\,$ for $\,d\not\equiv 0\,$ then $\,h\,$ is not bijective since $\,h(d)\equiv h(0).\,$ Thus we have proven that $\,h\,$ is bijective $\iff ax\equiv 0\,$ has *unique* solution $\,x\equiv 0\,$ (i.e. $\,\ker h\equiv 0\,$ in linear algebra language).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49250/discussion-between-sakthi-and-bill-dubuque).

Comment: ok. i am here. reading your reply.

Comment: Also note that because the residues mod $\,m\neq 0\,$ are a *finite* set there is no distinction between maps being bijective vs. surjective (onto) vs. injective $(1\!-\!1)$, by the Pigeonhole Principle.  $\ $

Comment: I am trying to understand your proof but having some difficulties. Is proving "$h$ is bijective if and only if $gcd(a,m)=1$"      the same as proving    "$h$ is NOT bijective if and only if $gcd(a,m)\neq 1$" ?

Comment: $ax\equiv 0(mod\;m)$ and $x\not\equiv 0(mod\;m)$ means $m|ax\wedge m\not|x$. Which means $m$ has to divide $a$ which means $gcd(a,m)=m>1$.

Comment: I am leaving. Please leave ur comments. Will read them tomorrow. Thanks.